# Object reference not set to an instance of an object, but is?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, oop

I must be missing something here, but I've got an instance of my submission object called up, in scope, and when I try to use it in another line, I throw this error about not setting the reference to an instance. What gives?

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    string x = Request.QueryString["SubmissionId"];

    SubmissionService ss = new SubmissionService();
    Submission sub = ss.getSubmissionByID(x);

if (sub.Status1.Equals(0))
    {
        PanelComment.Visible = false;

    }
    else
```

Comment: Are you sure ss.getSubmissionByID(x); is not returning null?

Comment: @Brazos if you changed `getSubmissionByID()` according to my suggestion in your previous post, there is a chance it might return null. Try `if (sub!= null && sub.Status1 == 0)`

Comment: Exactly, as well check value of string x

Comment: No, it's not null. When I comment out this block, the relevant data shows up.

Comment: Step Through your code once and see which one is returning null?

Comment: @Rahul, the queried value 'x' is pulled from a datakey field in a gridview on another page, which is populated by non-null supporting table fields.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible that the Status1 property on your submission object 'sub' is null...

Comment: So it is. Overlooked that field in my query on that method. I'm really bringing my A game today. Duh. Thanks to you and @Bas, as well as the helpful commenters.

Answer (score 3):

These could be null:

```
ss 
sub
sub.Status1
x
```

Put a breakpoint, and debug...

Answer (score 1):

Given the code that you supplied, there can be three causes:

1. the "Status1" property is null, this would generate a NullReferenceException.
2. PanelComment is null
3. sub is null

Comment: ss could not be null after a constructor call

Answer (score 0):

Given the code, the following properties could be null:

- Submission sub (If there is no submission with the ID = x)
- sub.Status1
- List item

PanelComment

Just change your code by the following:

```
Submission sub = String.IsNullOrEmpty(x) ? null : ss.getSubmissionByID(x);

if (sub!= null && sub.Status1 == 0){
...
```

It should fix most of the null references.